# Geodesics that paint curves on the projective space bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a geodesically complete connected riemannian manifold.

Let $p \in M$ be a point and $c: \mathbb{R} \to M$ an arbitrary geodesic that doesn't intersect p. **Our aim is to find a "nice" map sending points on the curve $c$ to tangent lines at $p$.**

Pick a point $q$ on the curve $c$ and connect it with $p$ via a geodesic curve (this is possible by completeness of $M$). Here is the relavent picture:

[image]

Every such geodesic corresponds to a unique tangent line through $p$. Ideally we want to have a cannonical choice of such geodesic for every point of $c$. Assuming there is such a choice we could obtain a function $f: c(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{P}T_pM$. where $\mathbb{P}T_pM$ is the tangent projective space or equivalently the fibre at $p$ of the $(1,dim(M))-$grassman bundle over $M$.

Now my question has two parts:

1) Given a initial point $q$ and an initial choice of geodesic connecting $p$ and $q$, is there then a cannonical choice for every other point on $c$? What i have in mind is a choice that "minimizes" in some suitable sense the variation of the geodesics with respect to variation of the initial point $q$. (I'm not so familiar with jacobi fields but i have a strong sense that this is what's missing here).

2) Under what conditions on $M$ is the map $f$ (defined above) smooth (resp. continuous) as a curve in $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ where $n=dim(M)$. By which i mean the composition $f \circ c : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{P}T_pM \cong \mathbb{R P}^{n-1}$ is smooth (resp. continuous).

Here's the picture I'd like to have in mind in this context. It might be wrong though, so you better take it with a **pint** of salt.

[image]

**Note:** The picture is far from being literal. $M$ is drawn as a surface so the fiber should be a projective line while i drew a projective plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by "nice", but here is a construction. Let  $q=c(0)$. Then $c$ lifts to a parameterized straight line $\tilde {c}$ in the tangent space $T_qM$, such that $c(t)=\exp_q(\tilde{c}(t))$. The point $p$ lifts (noncanonically, unless $\exp_q$ is a diffeomorphism) to a point $\tilde{p}\in T_q(M)$. Now, connect $\tilde{p}$ to $\tilde{c}(t)$ by straight line segments in $T_qM$. These segments project to the required curves $a(s,t)$ in $M$ connecting $p$ to $c(t)$. The velocity vectors 
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial s} a(s,t)|_{s=0}
$$
define the lines in $T_pM$ that you are asking for and, hence the map to $PT_pM$.

Note that the curves $a(s,t)$ above are not geodesics (in general). In order to use geodesics you have to assume that for the geodesics $\gamma(s,t)$ connecting $p$ to $c(t)$, the points $p, c(t)$ are not conjugate (otherwise you cannot make a smooth choice of $\gamma(s,t)$). For instance, if you assume that $M$ has nonpositive curvature, you can use geodesics $\gamma(s,t)$ for the construction.  The clean way to do so is to lift $c$ to the tangent space $T_pM$ via the exponential map $\exp_p$ (since it is a covering map by Cartan-Hadamard theorem) and then use straight line segments to connect via the same procedure I described above.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if i understood all of your requirements well.To the extent it is clear to me, a geodesic flow field of the type you suggest is certainly possible in reply to first part of your question. The following from Wolfram Alpha demonstration needs only a minor modification to be suitable to your description.

From the link suggested you can pick one out of three geodesic regimes for *returning* geodesics behavior at hyperbolic points (saddle points, *Gauss curvature negative*) with  low $ \alpha $ and high initial height.

A minimum of two geodesics possible, infinitely many also by rotation.

In this option geodesics go to a minimum radius as per Clairaut's Law on surfaces of revolution and cannot proceed beyond the tangential  *circle of no return* by virtue of invariant minimum radius in-built.They are tangential  to a circle of radius $ r \sin \alpha$ after boundary ring is touched before returning.

The pattern can be made ( by design) to return, or go to infinity on the other side of the surface which can be open/closed. CNC filament winding is performed on vessels of light weight design.

[FilamentShell](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8116/8659258489_c025bb1a39_z.jpg)

The other two options ( non-returning and asymptotic minimum radius ) are not  suitable.

The start point can be converted to line ( as a line to line map ) or its points can be picked/isolated.

I can prepare to upload another image to required dimensions if requirement of second part of your question  is more clear with suitable examples.

[HyperboloidGeodesics](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HyperboloidGeodesics/)